# Browsers performance in OS X

Tags: safari, google-chrome, performance

This is to collect the UI performance experiences we have with browsers in OS X.
I don't care about the benchmarks I care about how fast the UI responds to the user's actions.

I have come to the following conclusions:

- Chrome tab switching is the fastest.
- Safari sometimes is unresponsive (shows the waiting cursor) even for simple HTML pages with out having a lot of tabs open. This has never happened in Chrome.
- Safari's Javascript Cancvas drawing is the fastest.
- Safari's location bar recommendations is the fastest.

I expect your own observations.

Comment: this is a question that can't really have an "answer", or even several excellent opionions! browsers are always changing and every user uses them differently!

Comment: but I think it's a good question and not ranked as subjective.

Comment: Maybe it could be a Community Wiki where we add information as the time passes.

Comment: Seriously, it's a matter of RAM. Get more RAM and you will see dramatic improvements concerning responsiveness when many tabs are open simultaneously. You need at least 4GB. I had 2GB and was frustrated like you and upped to 8GB and it's like night and day. Looking at Activity Monitor, I was ALWAYS using all 2GB and now that I have 8GB, I find that I'm usually using 3-5GB. So I recommend 4GB or, if you can afford it, 8GB. Anything more is overkill though. Got 8GB from Amazon for $130, by the way.

Answer (score 3):

Lifehacker actually did [an article](http://lifehacker.com/5577951/browser-speed-tests-the-latest-chrome-firefox-opera-and-safarion-a-mac) on this with [hard data](http://spreadsheets.google.com/ccc?key=0AkFKjXybKbHNdF9iRXdtY2xrSE0tUlNSTnh0d0VKZFE&hl=en&authkey=CJK9ivsC):